# Python, most efficient way to subplot pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a subplot of 9 (in this example but the number would be variable for other use cases) line graphs showing the count of data points by county/area.

So far I have:

```
Surrey1 = df[df.county == 'Surrey']
Surrey2 = Surrey1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()


East_Sussex1 = df[df.county == 'East Sussex']
East_Sussex2 = East_Sussex1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()

West_Sussex1 = df[df.county == 'West Sussex']
West_Sussex2 = West_Sussex1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()


Buck1 = df[df.county == 'Buckinghamshire']
Buck2 = Buck1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()


Norfolk1 = df[df.county == 'Norfolk']
Norfolk2 = Norfolk1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()


Suffolk1 = df[df.county == 'Suffolk']
Suffolk2 = Suffolk1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()

Essex1 = df[df.county == 'Essex']
Essex2 = Essex1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()

Kent1 = df[df.county == 'Kent']
Kent2 = Kent1.county.groupby(df.date_stamp).value_counts()

# Create the fig
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=1, figsize=(12,6))

# Now plot
pd1_N.plot(ax = axes[0], subplots=True, legend=False) 
pd2_S.plot(ax = axes[1], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd3_ES.plot(ax = axes[2], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd4_WS.plot(ax = axes[3], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd5_B.plot(ax = axes[4], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd6_S.plot(ax = axes[5], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd7_E.plot(ax = axes[6], subplots=True, legend=False)
pd8_K.plot(ax = axes[7], subplots=True, legend=False)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Is there a quicker/more efficient way to do this? Tips on how to make the graph a little more presentable would be appreciated as well! 
Update:

I'm now using the a very simple function to do this quicker for a variable metric:

```
def plot_freq(metric, graph_width, graph_height):
    plot = str(metric)
    df.groupby(plot)['date_stamp'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot(subplots=True, figsize=(graph_width, graph_height))
    print("This plot shows the number of data points by", metric)
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're doing the same thing multiple times, you can likely define a list of the counties `county_list` you care about and then just use a loop `for county in county_list: do those two lines of code`. Or if you always want to do it for every county present in your dataset you can just do `for county in df.county.unique(): do things`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can condense this down to the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2017-10-01','2017-10-10',freq='D'), 500),'county':np.random.choice(['East Sussex','Buckinghamshire','Kent','Essex','Essex'],500)})

df.groupby('county')['Date'].value_counts().unstack(0).plot(subplots=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: nice and conscious ! :)

Comment: @MaxU Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew as I was typing that there had to be a better way!